# MongoDB pipeline conditional counting

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Documents in a collection contain `title`  and `active` fields. The `active` field is boolean. My goal is to group by `title` and count all the records. Lastly, I want to count the documents where `active` is true.

This query does the counting, but **total and active are always equal**. Why isn't the conditional counting only the documents where *active is `true`*?

Here is my pipeline:

```
[
    { 
        "$group" : { 
            "_id" : { 
                "student᎐campus᎐title" : "$student.campus.title"
            }, 
            "total" : { 
                "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
            }, 
            "active" : { 
                "$sum" : { 
                    "$cond" : [
                        { 
                            "active" : true
                        }, 
                        1.0, 
                        0.0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are evaluating [expression objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expression-objects) instead of [operator expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#operator-expressions)

Try below working version:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$title",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "active": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            "$active",
            1.0,
            0.0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OlLYNNnGbGO) for your reference.

---

EDIT: thanks to @wernfriedDomscheit 's advice, here is a more concise version using $toInt for MongoDB v4.0+

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$title",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "active": {
        "$sum": {
          "$toInt": "$active"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B8LSGsnGQxP)

Comment: Instead of `"$cond": ["$active",1.0, 0.0]` you can simply use `toInt: "$active"`